# How to use backslashes in the prefix of a (.JSON) snippet in the atom editor

Tags: latex, editor, code-snippets, atom-editor

I am trying to create a LaTeX snippet-set for the Atom editor. I'd like the backslash to act as an "active character", like in TexMaker.

I have the following in a file:

```
{
  ".text.tex.latex" : {
    "test1" : {
      "prefix":"test1",
      "body": "\\\\test1"
    },
    "test2" : {
      "prefix":"\test2",
      "body": "\\\\test2"
    },
    "test3" : {
      "prefix":"\\test3",
      "body": "\\\\test3"
    },
    "test4" : {
      "prefix":"\\\test4",
      "body": "\\\\test4"
    },
    "test5" : {
      "prefix":"\\\\test5",
      "body": "\\\\test5"
    },
    "test6" : {
      "prefix":"\\\\\test6",
      "body": "\\\\est6"
    }
  }
}
```

However, all but the first `"test1"` fails to add any autocompletion to the editor. I'm using the language-latex package.

I know I could just settle for writing `test1` and not `\test1`, but I like the TexMaker feeling of starting a snippet with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\text1'` etc for the prefix. That's what I did and it worked. Also checkout the [latex-language](https://github.com/area/language-latex) package, which already has a lot of the useful snippets.